# C Linked List : How to insert node at front

Tags: c, insert, linked-list

In the textbook "Fundamentals of Data Structures in C",
(by Horowitz Sahni Anderson-Freed)

they present the following code

as a method of inserting a node

after some arbitrary node x in a linked list :

```
void insertNode(nodePtr *listPtr, nodePtr insertLoc, int data)
{
   nodePtr temp = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(*temp));
   temp->data = data;
   if(*listPtr) // not empty
   {
       temp->next = insertLoc->next;
       insertLoc->next = temp;
   }
   else //empty
   {
       temp->next = NULL;
       *listPtr = temp;
   }
```

}

Therefore, the following calls would result to :

`nodePtr head = NULL;
   insertNode(&head,head,10);    // 10
   insertNode(&head,head,20);    // 10 -> 20 
   insertNOde(&head,head,30);    // 10 -> 30 -> 20`

My question :
**How is it possible to insert a node at the front of the list?**

Comment: Not with the given function. (the obvious way is `temp->next = *head; *head = temp;`)

Comment: @wildplasser I know it's a long time after the comment was posted, but how come you assign *head ( which is a node) to temp->next(which is a nodePtr) , aren't these two incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in the book is complete madness, IMHO. (maybe the book is about C++ ?)

- hiding a pointer behind a typedef is confusing, and bad style
- casting malloc()s return value is not needed, potentially dangerous, and bad style
- parentheses after sizeof are not necessary
- the function *design* is strange: passing three args where only two are needed, returning void.

A possible alternative function which *could* insert at the top, would be by using insertLoc instead of listPtr in the condition:

```
void insertNode(nodePtr *listPtr, nodePtr insertLoc, int data)
{
   nodePtr temp = malloc(sizeof *temp );
   temp->data = data;
   if (insertLoc) // Position requested
   {
       temp->next = insertLoc->next;
       insertLoc->next = temp;
   }
   else // No: insert at top
   {
       temp->next = *listPtr;
       *listPtr = temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: No it is not needed. if *head == NULL, the assignment `temp->next = *head;` will effectively set temp->next to NULL. -->> you don't need a special case, such as in your answer.

Comment: ok, you are right, i didn't see the trick temp->next = *listPtr; right away, but at least they do something different if yo call with head = NULL and and insertLoc != NULL ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Linked lists are a very simple data structure where each node contains a payload (int in your case) and a pointer to the next node. The list is terminated by a pointer to the special "NIL" node, in C usually just a NULL pointer.

[image: from wikipedia]
*Image: Yonkeltron at English Wikipedia*

To prepend to the list you just create a new node and assign its NEXT pointer to the previous head.

Also, don't forget to check the return value of malloc. Or use g_malloc from glib which does this automatically.

```
nodePtr cons(nodePtr tail, int data)
{
  nodePtr head = malloc(sizeof(*nodePtr));
  assert(head);
  head->data = data;
  head->next = tail;
  return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function, so a NULL insertLoc means insert as head

```
void insertNode(nodePtr *listPtr, nodePtr insertLoc, int data)
{
   nodePtr temp = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(*temp));
   temp->data = data;
   if(*listPtr) // not empty
   {
    if (!insertLoc) {
        temp->next = *listPtr;
        *listPtr = temp;
    } else {  
       temp->next = insertLoc->next;
       insertLoc->next = temp; 
    }
   }
   else //empty
   {
       temp->next = NULL;
       *listPtr = temp;
   }
}
```